# Heroku timeout on first request or on re-awakening

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails 4.1 app that operates normally and also has a page `/app` that acts as a single-page web application with Backbone + Marionette.

When I push to Heroku, my app will run just fine on all pages until I visit the `/app` page (which loads the Backbone environment), at which point the app will time out.  Subsequent requests from any device will work just fine.  If the dyno goes to sleep however, the first request after re-awakening it will also time out.

I assume this has something to do with asset precompilation, but it's not clear to me why the assets would expire if the dyno goes to sleep.

There are about 50 js files, which are about 300kb when compiled.

Is there a known issue or workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

My first instinct tells me you have a free tier heroku application with only one dyno. After one hour of inactivity your dyno will go to sleep. In order to wake it up again the first request your router sends will have some delay.

It might be that your /app path is rather heavy and takes long to load for the first time. Pretty much the same as with caching. When you have a heavy request it takes a lot of time to process it, but ones caching kicks in it is blazing fast.

I can't find any confirmation about the asset pipeline though, but if subsequent requests run just fine I can imagine the sleeping worker is the main cause. Perhaps you should implement a tiny rake task that prevents your worker from going idle. If the task is performed every 55 minutes for example, your worker will never sleep again.

Comment: What exactly is it caching?  On my local machine, the request loads in about 1.5 seconds (without compiling the files).  I would have thought that once the assets have been compiled for Heroku, they would stay compiled even through downtime.  For the production case, I would like to ensure that app restarts, new deploys, etc don't keep the site down for several minutes...

Answer (score 0):

The best workaround I can think of is to [use a CDN](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-amazon-cloudfront-cdn) for your assets, which will dissolve your app's dependence on Heroku's server, by requesting your assets from another system (typically S3 through CloudFront)

I can detail how to do this if you want

---

Secondly, as mentioned by `@Rails4Guides.com`, you should be aware that Heroku free tier has the limitation of making your dyno go to sleep after an hour of inactivity. This is to keep within the [750 hour free limit for AWS instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/awsgsg-intro/gsg-aws-free-tier-usage-limits.html) (which Heroku is built off)

To remedy this, you'll either need to [invest in another Dyno ($35/mo)](https://www.heroku.com/pricing), or as mentioned, run a small task to keep pinging your app each hour (keeping your dyno running)

Comment: Thanks, I have a paid dyno in production, but I'm more concerned about any downtime or errors in production causing this cache to be cleared and then the app will timeout for users again.  Not a great experience for them.  Is there a way to automatically compile/push the asset pipeline (or just js) files up to Cloudfront?

Comment: [asset_sync](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync) gem syncs with S3 - I believe you could get it to work with CloudFront